# How to correctly secure my REST-API

Tags: php, android, api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an android application and using firebase for the authentication. When a user signs up or logs in, I save the uid generated by firebase on my DB through my API which is built using laravel framework. How exactly do I go about protecting my API endpoints as authentication is not carried out through the API but with firebase? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though your authentication is completed by Firebase, you would just need to prevent unauthenticated requests to your API to be responded and this is done entirely on your API, once a user is authenticated through Firebase, you handle all control to your API, else return to Firebase for authentication.